# Как правильно задать вопрос для соревнования

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, соревнование

Я только недавно активно участвую в жизни ru.so, не знаю как правильно задать один вопрос и прошу помощи с этим тут.

Вопрос не конкретный, в этом и проблема. Я интересуюсь компьютерной графикой и хотел бы провести своего рода код-гольф. Мне известно про метку соревнование, с ней в принципе все понятно, кроме формирования критериев самого соревнования в моем случае.

Я хотел бы узнать о новых(для себя) способах генерации различных фракталов или других изображений, полученных по достаточно простой формуле. т.е примерный критерий соревнования "краткость базового алгоритма" так же критерием конечно же должен быть "интересность картинки", со вторым вообще огромный вопрос...

---

Например есть такая реализация цикла по всем пикселям на картинке:

```js
let c = canvas.getContext('2d'), 
    w = canvas.width, 
    h = canvas.height  

let formula = (x, y, cx, cy, m) => {
    // тут код базового алгоритма
    return [x, y*5, x+y]
}

canvas.onmousemove = e => {
    var img = c.getImageData(0, 0, w, h)
    for(var x = 0; x<w; x++) {
        for(var y = 0; y<h; y++) {
            let value = formula((2*x-w)/w, (2*y-h)/w, e.x/w, e.y/h)
            let offset = (y*w + x)*4    
            img.data[offset]     = value[0]*255
            img.data[offset + 1] = value[1]*255
            img.data[offset + 2] = value[2]*255
            img.data[offset + 3] = 255
        }
    }
    c.putImageData(img, 0, 0) 
}

canvas.onmousemove({x: 456, y: 123})
```

```html
<canvas width="600" height="175" id="canvas"/>
```

необходимо реализовать функцию `formula` для получения "интересного" изображения

---

Больше всего меня смущает что это получается очень размыто и вообще оффтопик.

Что посоветуете?

Comment: связь: [Заготовки справочных материалов про вопросы–соревнования](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11193/178576)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С соответствующими метками ([code-golf](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), [соревнование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5), [любой-язык](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d1%8e%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba)), считаю, вполне такие вопросы уместны. Главное чтобы был релевантный заголовок. Например:

```
простые способы генерации различных фракталов или других изображений
```

Comment: убедили, так и попробую

Comment: Эм.. А критерий победы как же?

Comment: @Qwertiy, имелось в виду, что детали можно и в самом вопросе указать) Хотя можно и заголовок вот такой сделать: `Самые короткие и простые способы генерации различных фракталов или других изображений`

Comment: Как-то не похоже: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/983698/178988

Comment: @Qwertiy, ну, наверное можно ТС-у правку предложить/коммент написать) Лично я не думаю, что эта деталь очень важна...

Comment: @Qwertiy критерий победы - сложный вопрос именно по этому я на мету написал сперва, я думаю это количество голосов за