# Заготовки справочных материалов про вопросы–соревнования

Tags: поддержка, статус-завершено, соревнование

В ответах к этому вопросу собраны черновики материалов про вопросы–соревнования, которые мы планируем добавить на сайт.  Пожалуйста, вносите правки для явных ошибок в оформлении. Замечания и предложения по содержанию публикуйте в вопросе [Пожалуйста, предложите улучшения в страницу справки про вопросы-соревнования!](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11197/6)

- [Страница справочного центра](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/11194/6).
- [Шаблон вопроса–соревнования](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/11195/6).
- [Вопрос-песочница для соревнований](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/11196/6).

Comment: Что-то "замечательного" убрали, а другую [багу](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11222/176217) не поправили.

Comment: И всё насмарку, [нарушающие правила конкурсы продолжают штамповать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1225740)

Comment: А, Николай тоже решил поддерживать нарушение своих собственных правил... Ясно, без вмешательства вышестоящего начальства сайт, видимо, уже не спасти.

Answer (score 4):

[статус-завершено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be)

## Страница справки

---

Заголовок: Вопросы-соревнования
Короткая ссылка: /help/code-golf

### Вопросы-соревнования на $SiteName

На $SiteName мы приветствуем вопросы–соревнования по программированию любых уровней, начиная от интересных прикладных задач и заканчивая олимпиадными заданиями.

Все вопросы-соревнования на $SiteName должны иметь:

1. **Четкое описание требований, предъявляемых к решениям**. Настоятельно рекомендуется использовать примеры.
2. **Объективный критерий победы**, который даст возможность выбрать лучшее решение из предложенных.

Как оказалось, вопросы–соревнования невероятно сложно написать верно. Поэтому мы рекомендуем использовать шаблон в качестве макета первой версии вашего вопроса. Если у вас нет стопроцентной уверенности в правильности вашего вопроса, опубликуйте его в песочнице вопросов–соревнований на Мете для получения отзывов и исправления недостатков до публикации в вопросах на основном сайте.

Все ответы в вопросах–соревнованиях должны:

- Удовлетворять требованиям, предъявляемым к решениям.
- Содержать решение, соответствующее постановке задачи.

Более подробную информацию о вопросах-соревнованиях можно найти в [описании метки «соревнование»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5/info).

### Вопросы–соревнования по визуализации

Программирование состоит из множества составляющих, в том числе алгоритмов, шаблонов проектирования и… визуализации. На $SiteName мы приветствуем вопросы–соревнования по визуализации, анимации и программированию графических компонентов интерфейса в общем.

#### Требования к оформлению вопросов-соревнований по визуализации

- Вопросы-соревнования по визуализации должны иметь *сценарий визуализации*. В сценарии должны быть указаны конкретные необходимые элементы (шаги) визуализации и ожидаемая от них совместная работа. При необходимости, каждый пункт сценария может иметь дополнительное разъяснения автора (продолжительность, повторяемость и т. д.)
- Ответы на вопросы–соревнования по визуализации должны содержать *реализацию хотя бы одного пункта сценария в виде работающего фрагмента кода*. Если представить решение в виде работающего фрагмента кода невозможно, то необходимо дополнить ваш код снимком экрана или .gif решения, работающего локально.

Пример оформления соревнования по визуализации «[Как создать анимированную иконку Stackoverflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1085360/28748)»

#### Критерии выбора победителя

В дополнение к объективному критерию победы, заданному автором вопроса–соревнования, ответ–победитель определяется как ответ, содержащий *как можно большее количество точно выполненных элементов сценария визуализации*. При наличии нескольких ответов, полностью выполнивших сценарий, выбирается ответ с наибольшим рейтингом.

### Вопросы–соревнования, конкурсы и конкурсные вопросы

[Конкурсные вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/?tab=bounties) — это вопросы на основном сайте, за которые кто–либо из участников назначил награду для привлечения внимания. [Подробнее о конкурсных вопросах](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty).

Конкурсы — это события в сообществе, которыми мы вместе привносим чуточку веселья в ежедневное участие на сайте, оставаясь в рамках правил сайта и сохраняя атмосферу знаний. Например, «[Новогодний алгоритм](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2235/6)». В рамках конкурса могут быть созданы несколько вопросов–соревнований. Конкурсы публикуются и проводятся на Мете, когда как их техническая составляющая, вопросы–соревнования, на основном сайте. За вопрос–соревнование может быть назначена награда. В случае назначения награды, вопрос-соревнование станет [конкурсным вопросом-соревнованием](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=Bounties).

Если вы не уверены, является ли ваш вопрос конкурсом или соревнованием, пожалуйста, задайте вопрос на Мете.

Comment: "Содержать решение, соответствующее критерию победы" Гм... может, "Содержать решение, соответствующее постановке задачи"? ну или около того.

Comment: @Akina Отличное предложение, спасибо! Поправил.

Answer (score 1):

[статус-завершено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be)

## Шаблон для вопросов-соревнований

---

Заголовок: Шаблон для вопросов-соревнований

- Есть какой-либо формат, который подходит для вопросов-соревнований?
- Есть ли шаблон, который я могу взять за основу для подготовки своего соревнования?

[faq] [поддержка]

---

### Ответ

---

Для написании вопроса-соревнования, вы можете следовать следующему формату.

---

## Введение

Кратко опишите задачу соревнования и предысторию, при необходимости. В описании, постарайтесь рассказать коллегам:

- Чем интересно это соревнование?
- Являетесь ли вы автором соревнования? При необходимости, укажите ссылки на источники.

Одного параграфа будет достаточно.

## Соревнование

Опишите соревнование во всех деталях. Описание любого соревнование должно включать:

- Полное описание всего, что подается на вход.
- Полное описание всего, что должно быть на выходе.
- Полное описание того, как связаны входные данные и результат на выходе.

Постарайтесь рассказать коллегам:

- Есть ли исключительные случаи? Если да, то как с ними поступать?
- Как определить победителя соревнования?
- На основе каких критериев следует оценивать ответы?

Будьте лаконичны: максимум важных нюансов о соревновании и минимум ненужных  деталей.

## Пример входных и выходных данных

Предоставьте как минимум один пример корректных входных данных и желаемого результата на выходе. Убедитесь, что примеры соответствуют вашему описанию соревнования.

Входные данные:

> Пример входных данных

Результат на выходе:

> Пример ожидаемого результата на выходе

...

---

### ***Разметка Markdown для копирования***

```
# Введение

Кратко опишите задачу соревнования и предысторию, при необходимости. В описании, постарайтесь рассказать коллегам:

 - Чем интересно это соревнование?
 - Являетесь ли вы автором соревнования? При необходимости, укажите ссылки на источники.

Одного параграфа будет достаточно.

# Соревнование

Опишите соревнование во всех деталях. Описание любого соревнование должно включать:

 - Полное описание всего, что подается на вход.
 - Полное описание всего, что должно быть на выходе. 
 - Полное описание того, как связаны входные данные и результат на выходе.

Постарайтесь рассказать коллегам:

- Есть ли исключительные случаи? Если да, то как с ними поступать? 
- Как определить победителя соревнования?
- На основе каких критериев следует оценивать ответы?

Будьте лаконичны: максимум важных нюансов о соревновании с минимум ненужных  деталей.

# Пример входных и выходных данных

Предоставьте как минимум один пример корректных входных данных и желаемого результата на выходе. Убедитесь, что примеры соответствуют вашему описанию соревнования.

Входные данные:

> Пример входных данных

Результат на выходе:

> Пример ожидаемого результата на выходе    

...
```

Comment: *Как определить победителя соревнования? На основе каких критериев следует оценивать ответы?* Не понимаю... что, каждый для себя сам будет определять, кто победил? А если нет, и кто-то будет подводить итоги и определять победителя, то "Как определяется победитель соревнования?" и "На основе каких критериев будут оцениваться ответы?"

Comment: @Akina Как я понимаю, именно автор вопроса определяет критерии победы и оценки. В этом вся суть конкурса. Подскажите, я правильно понял ваше замечание?

Comment: Да. Хотя лично мне идея субъективной оценки совершенно несимпатична.

Answer (score 0):

[статус-завершено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be)

## Песочница для вопросов–соревнований

---

Заголовок: Песочница для вопросов–соревнований

Создание понятного и хорошо проработанного вопроса–соревнования — сложная задача. Чтобы увеличить ваши шансы на успех, вы можете опубликовать вашу заготовку ответом в этом «вопросе–песочнице» ([что такое песочница](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_(software_development))), чтобы получить отзыв сообщества.

Для получения отзыва, пожалуйста, опубликуйте заготовку вашего соревнования в том виде, в котором вы планируете опубликовать его на основном сайте. Вы можете добавить несколько заметок, акцентирующих внимание на том, где бы вы хотели услышать мысли других участников. Вместе мы сделаем ваше соревнование лучше. Как только вы почувствуете, что ваше соревнование готово, опубликуйте его на основном сайте! После публикации на основном сайте, *замените содержимое вашего ответа в этом вопросе на ссылку на соревнование на основном сайте и удалите ваш ответ.*

#### Дополнительно

- Шаблон для вопроса-соревнования
- Страница справки о вопросах-соревнованиях

Comment: ссылка на вопрос песочницу и должна на wiki вести?

Comment: @Grundy Да. Это пояснение, что такое «песочница» в данном контексте.

Comment: По тексу больше похоже, что должна была быть ссылка на сам вопрос-песочницу

Comment: @Grundy Этот текста и есть текст вопроса–песочницы =P

Comment: Песочница на Мете будет или где?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Да, на Мете.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky надеюсь, на MSE. Кстати, вопрос-песочницу вероятно стоит сделать общим, чтобы мета-репутация не аффектилась.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, но на мете нет репутации. Если сделать общим, то при правках ответов они могут сменить авторство, что нехорошо.

Comment: @Qwertiy репутация есть для учета разнообразных бейджей. А поскольку шаг с вынесением песочницы соревнований на Мету от безысходности (по сути это к Мете не относится), то и аффектить какие-либо рейтинги Меты он не должен (или делать это по минимуму, если полностью исключить влияние нельзя). Если что, я вообще против этой песочницы на Мете.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, на codegolf'е она на мете. А нам она пока вообще не очень нужна, как мне кажется.