# Нужны ли праздничные, анимационные конкурсы?

Tags: обсуждение, соревнование

И так, дорогие друзья. Настали нелёгкие времена для ruSO`сарказм`

Разгорелся небольшой спор, нужны ли праздничные конкурсы анимации. Так давайте уже решим это!

Правила:

1. В ответе **СТОЯЩИЕ** аргументы, основывающиеся не только на личном мнении, а ещё на фактах из жизни сообщества.
2. В ответе правила проведения таких конкурсов.
3. Если вы голосуете за или против, то вы согласны со всеми правилами и утверждениями, которые предложил отвечающий.
4. Чуть не согласны с ответом - строчите свой ответ!
5. И **самое главное правило** - НИКАКОГО ТОКСИКА!!! Только факты и предложения

Ответ будет приниматься по кол-ву голосов! Тот ответ, у кого будет больше "+" тот и побеждает!

PS Для тех кто в танке! Праздничные конкурсы - конкурсы предназначенные для отпразднования даты/праздника, чисто чтобы развлечь сообщество и привлечь их внимание к веселью

Comment: Нужны, но только с привязкой к дате/праздникам, т.к. традиция.

Comment: Каждый давно решил -- для себя. Если вы считаете, что подобные конкурсы полезны -- то не надо обсуждать, кто и что думает (вспомним В. Маяковский "прозаседавшиеся"). Те, кто хотят, чтобы подобные конкурсы были разрешены -- должны пройти по процедуре изменения правил. Пока AFAIK [статус](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/11098/213987) не поменялся: "такие вопросы пока оффтопик, но можно поменять правила". Ключевое слово -- "ПОКА" (до сих пор). Вроде с этим все согласны, но дальше дело не пошло. Хотите ещё раз поговорить об этом?

Comment: @AK, хорошо, как пройти эту процедуру? Думаю, многие будут `ЗА`

Comment: Будут "за" что? Я например "за" и поддерживаю, но не настолько, чтобы тащить эту процедуру. И таких большиство думаю среди этих 21 проголосовавших "за". Есть ещё несколько человек, кто идёт и устраивает новые конкурсы (зная, что это оффтопик), но это тоже не те люди. Тут нужны люди-организаторы, но не в плане организации самих конкурсов (какую тему выбрать), а в плане мета-организации (процедура создания правил для правил), ближе к бюрократии.

Comment: @AK, согласен. Были бы у меня права - тянул бы всё это. Просто... Мне нравится идея сплочения всего сообщества. И даже под угрозой бана моего акка я готов говорить об этом хоть 100 раз, до тех пор, пока не примет решение(желательно "за") всё сообщество.

Comment: @DGDays зачем сразу бан :) если про новогодние - то они и так онтопик. Для остальных - ну вообще достаточно простая процедура, просто бюрократии много. Создаёте на мете вопрос  с указанием конкретных проблем. Описываете текущие проблемы (ака любые технологии, любой сценарий, накрутка репутации), пишете, что хотите сделать онтопиком с ограничениями, предлагаете ограничения в ответе, ждёте других ответов

Comment: @DGDays потом когда наберется голосов 20 за - можете считать что решили

Comment: А про новогодние конкурсы, что они онтопик, и про 20 голосов за - где можно в правилах почитать?

Comment: @DGDays, опубликуйте здесь "канонические ответы", за которые можно голосовать. (imho, в принципе, достаточно одного, можно будет посчитать плюсы и минусы по нему)

Answer (score 8):

[@DGDays](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11271/28748)

> 2. В ответе правила проведения таких конкурсов.

В конце декабря 2020 года, после [обсуждения на Мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/11194/28748) были опубликованы **[новые правила](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/code-golf)** проведения вопросов-соревнований.

Один из отдельных разделов новых правил:  **Вопросы–соревнования по визуализации** содержит требования к:

- допустимой предметной области соревнований по визуализации
- оформлению и содержанию стартового вопроса
- требования к содержанию ответа
- Критерии выбора победителя

На мой взгляд, все  основные требования, уже описаны в новых правилах.
Если выполнять эти требования, то есть чётко, однозначно сформулировать вопрос, обязательно добавить сценарий анимации, то такие конкурсы визуализации будут онтопиком.
Небольшое отличие от обычных конкурсов, будет состоять в том, что отвечающие могут иметь некоторую свободу в своих ответах при различных способах реализации конкретного пункта анимации.  На мой взгляд,  анимация невозможна без некоторой свободы.

От себя, я бы добавил рекомендацию TC, размещать в вопросе требование о недопустимости 100% копи-пасты.
Всё сказанное выше, касается обычных, текущих конкурсов анимации.

Что делать с праздничными конкурсами анимации, разрешить их в качестве исключения или **...**
нужно будет решить сообществу вместе с модераторским составом.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118258/discussion-on-answer-by-alexandr-tt----).

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, по вчерашнему спору думаю понятно собественно из-за чего я задал этот вопрос. Предлагаю ввести конкретный правила по анимациям, т.к. визуализация - нечто общее. Из-за этого andreymal применяет некорректно эти правила к конкурсу от Victor VosMottor и требует его закрытия

Comment: @DGDays прочитайте пожалуйста две крайних фразы из моего [ответа.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/11274/28748) Добавлю, что Конкурсы НГ невозможно вогнать в рамки правил. Об этом [я писал уже не раз](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9997/28748) Поэтому их надо либо разрешить в качестве исключения, как праздничного мероприятия, либо...

Answer (score 0):

Псевдоконкурсы, когда за конкурс выдается обычный некачественный вопрос, однозначно не нужны. Я надеюсь, реальный вопрос, который вы хотели задать, это нужны ли конкурсы/соревнования, не вписывающиеся в формат сайта вопросов и ответов, и какие именно конкурсы нужно разрешить.

Как уже написал Alexandr_TT, недавно утвердили страницу справки с правилами для конкурсов. Проблема в том, что утвержденные правила в части анимационных конкурсов абсолютно не соответствуют ожиданиям той части сообщества, которая хочет в них участвовать. Правила требуют иметь конкретный сценарий анимации, но анимационный конкурс с жестко заданным сценарием не очень интересен, так как это убивает всю креативность. Интересный конкурс должен быть, в некотором роде, по дизайну "слишком общим". Кроме того, если цель в пользе для базы знаний, то и она не достигается. Вопрос "анимируйте Деда Мороза, который едет на олене и машет левой рукой" ничем особо не лучше "анимируйте Деда Мороза по любому сценарию", никто не будет такое искать. Но и разрешить без ограничений анимационные конкурсы нельзя, так как тогда под их видом будут плодить некачественные вопросы (что уже было описано в знаменитой теме [Сообщество уже больше полугода поддерживает откровенный оффтопик. Доколе?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10370/)).

Думаю реальное решение тут в том, чтобы разрешить такие нечеткие анимационные конкурсы, но лишь с определенной периодичностью - либо в привязке к праздничным датам, например на Новый Год, либо просто установить, сколько раз в год мы будем их проводить, а конкретные даты определять обсуждением активных участников на мете или в чате. Правила для анимационных конкурсов тогда должны быть примерно такими:

> Анимационный конкурс должен содержать
>
> 1. Задание, которое описывает, какие изображения, персонажи или объекты нужно анимировать
> 2. Критерии победы (если голоса, указать явно)
> 3. Ограничения по технологиям, которые можно использовать

Это примерный набросок, и возможно его нужно будет подкорректировать тем, кто разбирается в анимациях. Конкурсы и псевдоконкурсы, созданные в нарушение установленной периодичности, должны будут закрываться модераторами, как только попадутся на глаза. Конкурсы, созданные до принятия правил, кроме новогодних, также должны быть закрыты.

Так можно достигнуть более реалистичного компромисса, чем если пытаться запихнуть конкурсы в рамки жестких сценариев. Если это ограничено по периодичности, сильного засорения базы знаний и обесценивания репутации не будет. Плюс можно по истечении времени вешать историческую блокировку, чтобы вопрос исчезал из списков по меткам и соответственно меньше попадался на глаза.

Comment: «разрешить такие нечеткие анимационные конкурсы, но лишь с определенной периодичностью» — только в правилах пожалуйста, а не в виде [самодеятельности модераторов на Мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/9961)